# including a Google dynamic map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need some help as I'm trying to call back a JavaScript function with PHP. I created 2 classes which work together perfectly. In the first one exploiting a Google API, I extract the latitude and longitude of a city chosen by a user on my form, and then I pass these values to the second class which exploits another API to show a weather forecast service for that city.

I'd like to add a Google map too, to create this way a more complete service showing a dynamic map with the chosen city.

I noticed with Firebug that the browser is not able to parse correctly the two mentioned properties of the object $map, as you can easily see by yourself.
I really don't know how to call back the js function inside the tag , I need for my purpose.

The simple echo I'm using here with PHP doesn't work here.

Hope someone can help me.
Here's [my page](http://newbielinux.altervista.org/weather.php)

and here's the piece of my code that is not working:

```
        /**
         * Check for the real existence of the city, using the 
         * property $status of the instanced GeoLocalization class, here the object $map.
         * This class exploits a Google API.
         */
         if ( isset($missing) && empty($missing) && strlen($citta) > 1 && $map->status == 'OK' )
            {    
                /**
                * Use some properties of the object $map to show my user 
                * the chosen city and state in Italian.
                * Show even the latitude and the longitudine.
                * These values are those passed to the GeoWeather class.
                */  

                // show the location                
                echo '<ul id="display_location">' . 
                        '<li class="rosso centra sottolineato grassetto">' . $map->formatted_address . '</li>' .
                        '<li>' . 'Latitudine: ' . $map->latitude . '</li>' .
                        '<li>' . 'Longitudine: '  . $map->longitude . '</li>' .
                      </ul>';

               echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>';                

               echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                        var map;
                        function initialize() {
                            var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 8,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $map->latitude . ", "  . $map->longitude; ?>)
                            };
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleStaticMap"), mapOptions);
                        }
                    </script>';

                echo '<script type="text/javascript">initialize();</script>';

                echo '<div id="googleStaticMap"></div>'; 
            }
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a new PHP-block inside a  PHP-block.

This:

```
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                var map;
                function initialize() {
                    var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $map->latitude . ", "  . $map->longitude; ?>)
                    };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleStaticMap"), mapOptions);
                }
            </script>';
```

should  be:

```
           echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    var map;
                    function initialize() {
                        var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 8,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng('. $map->latitude . ','  
                                                        . $map->longitude .')
                        };
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleStaticMap"), 
                                              mapOptions);
                    }
                </script>';
```

**Other issues:**

you must switch the order of these 2 lines(otherwise `#googleStaticMap` is unknown when you call the function):

```
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">initialize();</script>';

            echo '<div id="googleStaticMap"></div>';
```

**Additionaly:**

`#googleStaticMap` currently doesn't have a height. You've set a height of 100%, but as long as the parent element of `#googleStaticMap` doesn't have a height set via CSS this will not have any effect.

Comment: I tried to make all the changes you suggested as you can see now, but I still can't see this damned dynamic map.

I got no clue about it now! Everything should be ok, but.... Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: the map still doesn't have a height

Comment: I added a container id for the map, and I specified both the width and the height for it, which I repeated then in the map id itself. I implement this CSS style in the <head> part, and now it works great. You can put any city you like, and you'll see the results with the dynamic map. Thanks a lot.